# error occured when clicking a programatically added button

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to programatically generate buttons and add event handlers to them and i've succeeded in creating the buttons but when I click on one of the I get the following message **object reference not set to an instance of an object** .

Here is the code that creates the buttons:

```
    Dim i As Integer = 1
    For Each dtab As DataTable In ds.Tables
        For Each drow As DataRow In dtab.Rows
            If (CInt(drow(3)) < CInt(drow(4))) Then
                Dim l As New Label()
                With l
                    .Location = New System.Drawing.Point(30, 40 * i)
                    .Text = "product number  " & drow(0) & " has reached the minimal quantity"
                    .Width = 300
                    Panel3.Controls.Add(l)
                End With
                Dim b As New Button()
                With b
                    .Location = New System.Drawing.Point(350, 40 * i)
                    .Enabled = True
                    .Width = 100
                    .Text = "fill stock"
                    Panel3.Controls.Add(b)
                    AddHandler b.Click, AddressOf Me.Button_Click
                End With
                i = i + 1
            End If

        Next
    Next
```

the code that handels the button click is the following:

```
Private Sub Button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim co As New SqlConnection("server=JAMMINGJACK-PC\SQLEXPRESS ;initial catalog=td3;integrated security=true;")
    Try
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

        co.Open()
        cmd.Connection = co
        cmd.CommandText = "Update article set qteStck=(qteStck+(seuilmin*3)) where numart=" & drow(0) '
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        co.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, Me.Text)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two big problems on this line in your event handler:

```
cmd.CommandText = "Update article set qteStck=(qteStck+(seuilmin*3)) where numart=" & drow(0) '
```

The first problem is the code is crazy vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's a side-issue to the question, but this is **IMPORTANT**, and you should take a few minutes to Google parameterized queries and how to use them.

The second problem is with the `drow(0)` expression. That variable has no meaning in this method. It was scoped to the `For Each` loop in the code that created your buttons, but it has no meaning at all here. That this compiles at all means you either tried to re-declare it at the class level (which won't help; that will be a *different* `drow` variable) or turned `Option Strict` off, which is *very* poor practice.

There are several ways you can address this, such as encoding the `drow(0)` value in the`Tag` property or inferring it from the `Name`. My preferred approach here would be to create a custom control that groups your label and button together.

Comment: The tag property worked out perfectly, but I'm curious as to what did man by creating a custom control that groups the labels and the buttons together ? Could please elaborate more ?

Comment: It's a big topic (Google is your friend here). But basically, you create a new custom control in Visual Studio, and it gives you a panel. You drop a label and a textbox on the panel. Then you add a property for your drow(0) value, set up the event handler, expose whatever public properties you want to use (like .Text), and you can drop that on a form or create it in code in one step.